# How to get Microsoft Edge User-Agent from Local file?

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-edge, binaryfiles

i would like to get the User-Agent for Microsoft Edge from a local file in Windows 10.
(In other words, i want to get the User-Agent of MSEDGE currently installed on my PC without any outbound connection.)
Can you tell me which file it is contained in?
i don't care what method you use, as long as you can get an exact match to the actual User-Agent.
i am going to use Perl to get it. 
(Just tell me which file contains the User-Agent or how it is generated from a local file.)

Comment: If you can run that target Edge, you can evaluate the JavaScript expression `navigator.userAgent` to get the user-agent string.

Comment: @AKX i can understand that. if possible, it is preferable to be able to get the USERAGENT without running Edge, or to be able to get the USERAGENT on the console.
(This is because i expect to eventually use the UserAgent string from an external script.) thanks.

Answer (score -1):

my browser User-Agent was in the following format

- Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/zzz.z.zzzz.zzz Safari/537.36 Edg/XXX.X.XXXX.XX

(Win64; the x64 part also differs depending on the environment.)

The XXX.X.XXXX.XX part can be obtained from the following folder name.

- %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft\Edge\Application\XXX.X.XXXX.XX

(There may be multiple folders, but here i choose the one with the highest number.)

The zzz.z.zzzz.zzz part appears immediately after the string explicitly-allowed-ports inside the following file.

- %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft\Edge\Application\XXX.X.XXXX.XX\msedge.dll

by merging these, i decided to make it a UserAgent string.
i think msedge.dll is not so efficient because it is huge, but i achieved my goal tentatively.

if you have a better way, please answer/comment anytime. thanks.